# Does LTPA token expiration prevent sending of SOAP response to standalone application

Tags: soap, websphere-6.1, ltpa

I am using WebSphere 6.1 server.

In my application, we use web services for the communication of standalone client(Swing) with web part.

From web part, we use WebSphere MQ to communicate with the Pro*C part. When we trigger a button in client part, the web is called which in turn invokes the MQ for a response.

We face the below error when we do the above operation:

```
LTPAServerObj W   SECJ0371W: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Thu Nov 20 07:56:12 CET 2014, current Date: Thu Nov 20 13:58:28 CET 2014.
SRTServletRes W   WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
LTPAServerObj W   SECJ0371W: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Thu Nov 20 08:06:03 CET 2014, current Date: Thu Nov 20 14:01:36 CET 2014.
```

The MQ responses are OK as we trace the logs.

My Question:
Does this LTPA token expiration prevent my websphere server from sending the SOAP response to client part?

Comment: Do you have any security enabled/configured for your application or web services?

Comment: yes all web services from the application have to be requested  with web authentication.

Comment: If token expires, you should be prompted to reauthenticate. Server should not accept request, but redirect to authentication. Are you sure, that there is some automatic reauthentication in you app? Are you not getting responses to the application, when this happens, as it not clear from the question?

Comment: Hi Gas, We are getting the response from MQ. But we are not sure whether the response is sent from Web to client part as we get Time out exception.

Comment: So first fix the timeout problem. Then you can for test shorten LTPA token lifetime. But token expiration impacts request, not response.